# Should I declare my laptop in the passenger card?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australia

so I just got my student visa granted and I'll be going to Australia for the first time by next month
Im going to bring my Laptop $2000 , Tripod $140 , Camera $1600 and Ipad $800 which all worth more than $900 that I purchased while I was studying in overseas about 2-4 years ago

So my question is , should I declare this items that I bought 2-4 years ago in the Incoming passenger card ? 
Coz by what im understand is it is for new items that just bought overseas that is in box , but I just need to make sure that I right

Thanks !

Comment: I wouldn’t bother declaring those. I’d consider them used personal items.

Comment: Because you are moving to Australia, different rules may apply to you than to short-term visitors (which we deal with here). Please visit our sister site [expatriates.se] for help with this question.

Comment: See [here](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/duty-free) for an overview.  Further questions should be asked in [expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @k2moo4 wow thanks for that site man ,thats really helpfull !! Once again thank youu :)